# Accessing User Object in Function for Flask Limiter Returns Context Error

Tags: python, flask

I'm using the Flask-limiter extension to limit the number of page requests for a certain route (unless they are logged in as administrator).  I am using the Flask-Stormpath extension to manage my user authentication.

For some reason, my existing function returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 772, in <module>
    @limiter.limit("20/hour", exempt_when=admin_conditions())
  File "index.py", line 114, in admin_conditions
    if current_app.user.is_authenticated():
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 338, in __getattr
__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 297, in _get_curr
ent_object
    return self.__local()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 34, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
RuntimeError: working outside of application context
```

here is my code:

```
# Rate Limiting function
def admin_conditions():
    if user.is_authenticated():
        group_list = []
        for group in user.groups:
            group_list.append(group.name)

        if not group_list:
            return(False)
        else:
            if group_list[0] == "admins":
                return(True)
            else:
                return(False)
    else:
        return(False)

# route
@limiter.limit("20/hour", exempt_when=admin_conditions())
```

I read that the admin_conditions function is called in the [request context](http://flask-limiter.readthedocs.org/en/stable/#keyfunc-customization) by flask-limiter, but I don't understand how to access the user object from there.  Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the function to the decorator, not the result of the function.

```
@limiter.limit('20/hour', exempt_when=admin_conditions)
```

Notice the lack of `()`, so not calling the function immediately.  Currently, the function executes at definition time, before the app is running and a request is being handled.